# How to transform DF to add column with list of string contained within another column

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Say I have a list of keywords in scala

`val keywords = List("pineapple", "lemon")`

And a dataframe like so

```
+---+-------------------------------------------+
|ID |Body                                       |
+---+-------------------------------------------+
|123|I contain both keywords pineapple and lemon|
|456|I sadly don't contain anything...          |
|789|Pineapple's are delicious                  |
+---+-------------------------------------------+
```

How can I transform this dataframe to have a new column with the keywords that `Body` contains? The result I'm looking for is something like

```
+---+-------------------------------------------+------------------+
|ID |Body                                       |Contains_Keywords |
+---+-------------------------------------------+------------------+
|123|I contain both keywords pineapple and lemon|[pineapple, lemon]|
|456|I sadly don't contain anything...          |[]                |
|789|Pineapple's are delicious                  |[pineapple]       |
+---+-------------------------------------------+------------------+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check below code.

Creating dataframe with required sample data.

```
scala> val df = Seq(
      (123,"I contain both keywords pineapple and lemon"),
      (456,"I sadly don't contain anything"),
      (789,"Pineapple's are delicious")).toDF("id","body")

df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: int, body: string]
```

```
scala> val keywords = List("pineapple", "lemon")
keywords: List[String] = List(pineapple, lemon)
```

`typedLit` to add `keywords` to dataframe & use `filter` higher order function to check if that `keyword` contains `body` column.

```
scala> df
.withColumn("keywords",typedLit(keywords))
.withColumn("Contains_Keywords",expr("filter(keywords,keyword -> instr(lower(body),keyword) > 0)"))
.show(false)
```

Final output

```
+---+-------------------------------------------+------------------+------------------+
|id |body                                       |keywords          |Contains_Keywords |
+---+-------------------------------------------+------------------+------------------+
|123|I contain both keywords pineapple and lemon|[pineapple, lemon]|[pineapple, lemon]|
|456|I sadly don't contain anything             |[pineapple, lemon]|[]                |
|789|Pineapple's are delicious                  |[pineapple, lemon]|[pineapple]       |
+---+-------------------------------------------+------------------+------------------+
```

Answer (score 2):

You can convert the keywords list to a dataframe, then join based on an `rlike` condition. It's good to add `\\\\b` before and after the keywords to specify word boundaries, so that you can prevent partial matches, e.g. `apple` matching `pineapple`.

```
val result = df.as("df")
    .join(keywords.toDF("keywords").as("keywords"), 
          expr("lower(df.body) rlike '\\\\b' || keywords.keywords || '\\\\b'"), 
          "left"
         )
    .groupBy("id", "body")
    .agg(collect_list("keywords").as("Contains_keywords"))

result.show(false)
+---+-------------------------------------------+------------------+
|id |body                                       |Contains_keywords |
+---+-------------------------------------------+------------------+
|123|I contain both keywords pineapple and lemon|[pineapple, lemon]|
|789|Pineapple's are delicious                  |[pineapple]       |
|456|I sadly don't contain anything             |[]                |
+---+-------------------------------------------+------------------+
```